# How do I DISPLAY div with CSS transition based on screen size?

Tags: css, transition

My DIV with a class is hidden until the browser size is 1,000px width.

How do I make a the DIV fade in once the browser size makes it appear using CSS?

Here is my current code.  It does not work.

Thank you for any help.

```
.instaWRAP {
    display: none;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 5s linear;*
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .instaWRAP {display: inline}
}
```

Comment: In your css `opacity` was never changed, so there's no transition. And by the way, `display` is not an animatable property, don't try to transition it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your media query:

```
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
   -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
    -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
     -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
        animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: Where do put this?  THis makes everything global?  I only want this for the .instaWRAP class.

Comment: Yes, this will work globally. But only that time, when you use `animation: fadein`, you can change the name and name it `instaWRAP` or something  similar. You need to put it whenever into CSS file. The first 5 lines needs to be in that media query `.instaWRAP` class.